# Laravel - Register don't save form response in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do a register page but data are not send in my database. And I don't have any error.

Here is the controller : (Generated by Laravel)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\PostUser;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    protected $primaryKey = "id_biodiv_acteur";
    protected $table = "acteur";

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/pages/users';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'string|max:255',
             ...            
            'picture' => 'image'
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        dd($request->all());
        return PostUser::create([
            'nom' => $data['name'],
            'prenom' => $data['surname'],
             ...
            'image' => $data['picture']
        ]);
    }
}
```

The var dump and the die doesn't work so create() is not call. And i'm not redirect aafter enter the form, it just reload the page

My register.blade.php :

```
<div class="add-content container">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        <h1>&bull; Ajouter un utilisateur &bull;</h1>
        <div class="underline"></div>

        <form action="{!! route('register') !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" role="form">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <div class="column-left">

                <label class="has-float-label" for="name">
                    <input class="" type="text" placeholder="" name="name" required>
                    <span>Nom</span>
                </label>

                <label class="has-float-label" for="password">
                    <input class="" type="password" placeholder="" name="password" required>
                    <span>Mot de passe</span>
                </label>

                ...

                <label class="has-float-label" for="picture">
                    <input type="file" name="picture" multiple>
                    <span>Ajoutez des images</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="button">Enregistrer</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And a model i added to the controller (PostUser.php) :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class PostUser extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = "id_acteur";
    protected $table = "acteur";

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'prenom',
         ...
        'image'
    ];
}
```

My last update of create() :

```
protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'string|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'birthDate' => 'date',
            'mobile' => 'required|string|max:45',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:acteur',
            'city' => 'string|max:255',
            'type' => 'string|max:45',
            'numberMember' => 'string|max:255',
            'acessNumber' => 'int|max:11',
            'gender' => 'string|max:45',
            'fax' => 'string|max:45',
            'telephone' => 'string|max:45',
            'adress' => 'string|max:255',
            'postalCode' => 'string|max:16',
            'motivation' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'state' => 'string|max:45',
            'picture' => 'image'
        ]);

        return PostUser::create([
            'nom' => $data['name'],
            'prenom' => $data['surname'],
            'mot_de_passe' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'pays' => $data['country'],
            'date_naissance' => $data['birthDate'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'ville' => $data['city'],
            'type' => $data['type'],
            'num_adherent' => $data['numberMember'],
            'niveau_acces' => $data['accessNumber'],
            'civilite' => $data['gender'],
            'fax' => $data['fax'],
            'telephone' => $data['telephone'],
            'adresse' => $data['adress'],
            'code_postal' => $data['postalCode'],
            'raison_sociale' => $data['motivation'],
            'statut' => $data['state'],
            'image' => $data['picture']
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand that you are using `use RegistersUsers;` which is trait. So open up that file and see yourself that in fact you do have both register and showRegistrationForm methods.

Comment: Why you are calling `User::create` this as you have `PostUser` model

Comment: Ow yes sorry i didn't saw that

Comment: I fixed that Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was the HTML which was wrong, now my html look like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="add-content container">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <h1>&bull; Ajouter un utilisateur &bull;</h1>
    <div class="underline"></div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="column-left">

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="has-float-label">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
                    <span>Nom</span>
                </label>

                 @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            ...

             <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('picture') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="picture" class="has-float-label">
                    <input id="picture" multiple type="file" class="" name="picture" value="{{ old('picture') }}" required>
                    <span>Ajoutez des images</span>
                </label>

                @if ($errors->has('picture'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('picture') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>

        </div>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

And in RegistersUsers.php i remove after the $request on this line"->all"

```
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer following code.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
           'nom' => 'required',
           'surname' => 'required',
            ]);
    $create = PostUser::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Okay i changed the name, how do i check the record of "acteur" ? With a var_dump ?

Comment: I can see if there is a record via phpmyadmin, I tried to do a var_dump and a die in the function create but nothing happened so this function is not even call

Comment: Huuum, nothing happened i did what you said. Maybe the issue is in html because i'm not even redirect to /pages/users

Comment: I change this: Route::post('/create', ['as' => '/create', 'uses' => 'RegisterController@create']); in this: $this->post('/create', ['as'=>'create','uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@create']); in Router.php. The dd worked well, i put the result in the question.

Comment: Yes but these data are not validated by validator() ? It need to pass by the validated() then by create()

Comment: i can't make a $request->all because i need to put a bcrypt on the password, i showed you exactly my code in the last update of the question. It's not working

Comment: You helped me but your answer don't solve my problem :/ And i don't think that modify the routes is a good idea because you escape the Laravel system

Comment: I have solved many of the problems and we can write any routes that we want. And how can you say that I have escaped laravel system? I am working on laravel since 2.5 years. You have to learn laravel. You don't know basics. You are accepting $data variable in create method instead of Request. Anyways tried to help you lot and wasted my time.

Comment: Thanks you for the help and your time, but the fact is that i sucess too solve myself my issue, and the problem was not really in the controller. Anyway thank you again and i'm sorry if i hurt you.